# Can any function be written as a composition of other functions?

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

Can any function be written as a composition of other functions? For example, can a polynomial $h(x)$ be written as $k(g(x))$?

Comment: Well, any function $f(x)$ can be written as $f(g(x))$, where $g(x)=x$.

Comment: Consider the case of $h(x)=x$ and $h(x)=k(g(x))$.  Then $k$ is the functional inverse of $g$.  When $g(x)=x^2$, that would imply that $k(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ which is **not** a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the "extension problem" or the "lifting problem" depending on which one you fix ($f$ or $g$, where $h = g \circ f$). Its answer depends on what field or ring your polynomials are over (or more generally, what category you are working in). For a nice introductory treatment see Lawvere and Schanuel's "Conceptual Mathematics" page 45.

Answer (score 0):

Every function can be written as a composition, using the identity function: $h = h \circ \text{id} = \text{id} \circ h$

Your particular example will only work for some polynomials. E.g. $h(x) = 2x - 42$ can not be composed using your given functions.
$$
h = k \circ g \Rightarrow \\
k = h \circ g^{-1}
$$
Thus $k(x) = 2\sqrt{x} - 42 $ which is not a polynomial.